# Beginning Executable Hacking/Decompiling/Debugging

Tags: debugging, executable, reverse-engineering, decompiling

I am comfortable in C#/Java, and I know C and C++ fairly well. However, I want to dig deeper and learn more bare-metal stuff. For example, a simple console program in C++:

```
int main()
{
    char *ptr = "helloworld";
    return 1;
}
```

I opened it in Visual Studio using the debugger (after deleting the pdb file) to step through the code in assembly. I am also using HxD hex editor to look at the binary.

Obviously I am far from understanding what's going on. I want to learn how to trace code as it's executing for a binary I don't have the source to (if possible), or just learn as much about this subject as I can. I understand step-through debugging with source as I use it every day at work, but without it I am helpless.

Is there a 'ground up' tutorial for this type of thing?
What tools/walkthroughs can you recommend?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to go deeper take a look at Ollydbg and some reversing/cracking tutorials.. That will take deep for sure :) And you will learn how stuff works :)
[Reverse Engineering Team](http://www.reteam.org/) is a good starting point.. Any search engine will give you lots of stuff with the right keywords.. :)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to understand assembly at the very least. I would practice writing a few (somewhat trivial) programs in order to gain a grasp of the opcodes, register, stack usage, etc.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly

Comment: The Intel reference manuals are pretty useful too. And OllyDbg 2 has an integrated mini assembler docu which you can use to quickly get information about your selected command.

Answer (score 2):

Books:

1. About Assembler - on your own taste;
2. Some books about the OS (Jeffrey Richter, Helen Custer, Matt Pietrek are still actual?)
3. "Art of Computer Programming" by Knuth (do not ask why).
4. Intels/AMD documentation about their procs (or which one are you going to hack for?)

Tools/Soft:

1. Soft Ice.
2. IDA Pro.
3. HEX Editor (you said you already have one).
4. DDK (now it is called WDK - Windows Driver Kit).
5. As many compilers SDKs as you can.

Follow [this guy](http://ru.linkedin.com/in/nezumi).

I hope nobody is going to treat <del>this question and</del> this answer seriously :)

Comment: Thanks... although I'm not sure what you mean by that last statement.

Comment: @Trust I came to RE 6 years ago and was very enthusiastic on it... I listed tools I used. I updated my last statement to refer to my answer only, sorry :) The key point is that it is a very long way. "Hacking" has its wow-effect, but it is a very hard work...

Comment: I shouldn't have used the word 'hacking' because it is easily misinterpreted to mean 'cracking' - which is not what I want to do. Your answer is helpful, though.

Answer (score 2):

I did not know why nobody has mentioned Lena's tutorials on Reverse Engineering. 
I personally found them very helpful. You can find them here [www.tuts4you.com](http://www.tuts4you.com) 
But you need to understand some basic assembly like (jmp etc., registers) and I do not need to mention a fair understanding of programming (I am sure you have it ) 
 Also there are loads of crackme's which you can work on to improve yourself.